# Presto integration with hive is not working

Tags: hadoop, hive, presto, trino

I installed Hadoop 3.2.1 and top of hadoop installed hive 3.1.2 on
single node centos7 and wanted to integration with Presto search engine so 
that i can see the databases of hive into presto- server- 0.229.Hive is working perfectly and able to create table and i have done installation and configuration of presto-server-0.229 with help of official document. But i am not able to access the databases from presto.

```
  Here are my all configuration details:

  Hive-site.xml:
  <property>
          <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
          <value>jdbc:mysql://10.0.0.96/metastore_db?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true</value>
          <description>metadata is stored in a MySQL server</description>
          </property>

          <property>
          <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName</name>
          <value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value>
          <description>MySQL JDBC driver class</description>
          </property>

          <property>
          <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName</name>
          <value>hiveuser</value>
          <description>user name for connecting to mysql server </description>
          </property>

          <property>
          <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword</name>
          <value>hivepassword</value>
          <description>password for connecting to mysql server </description>
          </property>

          <property>
          <name>hive.metastore.uris</name>
          <value>thrift://10.0.0.96:9083</value>
          <description>Hive metastore Thrift server</description>
          </property>
  Presto Directories and files details:
  drwxrwxrwx  3 root root     98 Nov 21 05:58 bin
  drwxr-xr-x  3 root root     87 Nov 22 10:55 etc
  drwxrwxrwx  2 root root   8192 Nov 21 05:30 lib
  -rwxrwxrwx  1 root root 191539 Nov 15 05:57 NOTICE
  drwxrwxrwx 31 root root   4096 Nov 21 05:30 plugin
  -rwxrwxrwx  1 root root    126 Nov 15 05:57 README.txt
  [root@master presto-server-0.229]# cd etc/
  [root@master etc]# ll
  total 12
  drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  51 Nov 23 20:38 catalog
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 240 Nov 22 10:55 config.properties
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 171 Nov 21 05:33 jvm.config
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 104 Nov 21 05:31 node.properties
  [root@master etc]# cd catalog
  [root@master catalog]# ll
  total 8
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 173 Nov 23 20:38 hive.properties
  -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  19 Nov 21 06:01 jmx.properties
  [root@master catalog]# cd ..
  [root@master etc]# cd ..
  [root@master presto-server-0.229]# cd bin/
  [root@master bin]# ll
  total 14708
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root     1450 Oct  9 21:28 launcher
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root       78 Nov 15 06:12 launcher.properties
  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root    14173 Oct  9 21:28 launcher.py
  -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 15033453 Dec 15  2018 presto
  drwxrwxrwx 4 root root       47 Nov 15 06:12 procname

  -rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 173 Nov 23 20:38 hive.properties
  -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  19 Nov 21 06:01 jmx.properties

  hive.properties file configuration:

  [root@master catalog]# cat hive.properties
  connector.name=hive-hadoop3
  hive.metastore.uri=thrift://10.0.0.96:9083

  Please help me
```

Answer (score 3):

Presto .229 does not support Hive 3.

Hive 3 is currently supported:

- by [Starburst Presto 323-e](https://www.starburstdata.com/starburst-presto-sql/) (`connector.name` is still `hive-hadoop2` though)
- by Presto on Qubole's platform (I don't know the configuration details).

Presto's work on Hive 3 support is in progress and you can track it here: https://github.com/prestosql/presto/issues/1218.

Since you're likely to have follow-up troubleshooting-like questions which do no really fit SO, I recommend that you join the `#troubleshooting` on [Presto Community Slack](https://prestosql.io/slack.html). If you go with [Starburst Presto](https://www.starburstdata.com/starburst-presto-sql/) option, there is `#starburst` channel as well on that slack.

Comment: @RaviKumar which version you mean? .229 will work with Hive 3 only **very partially**, so it depends whether you use any Hive 3 specific features (transaction tables, timestamp columns, hadoop erasure coding, etc.). And whether you use HDP.